# For some reason {{ post.message }} is not displaying the modle

Tags: python, html, django

I am making a simple site to experiment with manipulating user data. I have a form where the user enters in some info and once they hit submit they get redirected to a new page. On this new page, the info they entered is supposed to be displayed. I am under the impression that you use this {{ Modle_Name.Fild_name}} to inject the info into the HTML. However, it is not working. If any of y'all have a solution I would much appreciate it.

sucseus.html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>success</h1>
<h2>{{ post.message }}</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from . import forms
from forums_simple.models import Post
# Create your views here.


class Form(generic.CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'forums_simple/form.html'
    fields = ['message']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('forums:sucsseus')

class Sucsessus_view(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'forums_simple/sucseus.html'
    model = Post
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass it as a context. The best way to do it is via `DetailView`.

```
class Sucsessus_view(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'forums_simple/sucseus.html'
    model = Post
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('post/<int:pk>/', Sucsessus_view.as_view(), name='sucsseus'),
    ...
]
```

Comment: I tried that and for some reason it is giving me this error now: Reverse for 'working' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['forums/sucseuss/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: Then you are referencing some `working` url that you don't have in your `urls`. You should be careful, because sometimes u write `sucsseus`, sometimes `sucseus`.

Comment: I did that and have been trying other things but I still get the error for some reason. I think it has something to do with my reverse_lazy.

Comment: @EthanKoch Show your urls, I believe there can be a problem. The error says a lot. You are trying to get `forums/sucseuss/` and probably you have `forums/sucseuss/<pk:int>` or something like that. But I don't see your `working`. You have to share parts that are shown in the error. And the full error message sometimes helps.

Answer (score 0):

here are my URLs

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'forums'

urlpatterns = [
    path('sucseuss/<int:pk>/', views.Sucsessus_view.as_view(), name='working'),
    path('forum/', views.Form.as_view(), name='form')
]
```